# How do you make a static function/method in c++?

Tags: c++, static

I am just learning C++. I already know C and Java. Could someone please show me how to create a static method/function in C++ like I would in Java. For example, just for practice I am writing a Student class with the standard information (name, student number, gpa, etc). I want to make a static method/function that would return the total number of student objects created. I know in Java it would be:

```
public static int getNumStudents () {
    return totalStudentsCreated; // global variable
}
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: I know. lol Someone else did. That's why I'm saying thanks.

Comment: @user3286381 Just a friendly tip, it's not about being an "arrogant jerk", it's about the level of research you haven't done. [A quick search for "c++ static function"](https://www.google.com/#q=c%2B%2B+static+function) shows any number of useful results in the first page alone. In general, questions with answers that can be found via a quick search are disapproved of here. In the future, if you research questions a bit better, you'll probably have find much better results in terms of the votes you get. Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with @computerfreaker. I gave a +1 though as I have not managed to find a duplicate just yet, but either way, yeah, what computerfreaker wrote.

Comment: You're assuming that whatever I found on the web or in a textbook was helpful. I did look at those places and did do research before posting the question. I didn't find the explanations helpful. They were often vague and convoluted. I'm doing an honours degree in computer science at university. I'm not some lazy idiot. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I gave a +1 since I know understanding coding concepts in other languages can be challenging. And, even if there were answers out there at the time, they may not be very helpful to a beginner.

Comment: That's exactly what happened actually. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how in C++

```
class Student {
   private:
      static int totalStudentsCreated;
   public:
      static int getNumStudents();
};

int Student::totalStudentsCreated = 0;

int Student::getNumStudents() { return totalStudentsCreated; }
```

Should be covered in your C++ text book

Comment: When using header files (.h) and implementation files (.cpp), are totalStudentsCreated and getNumStudents required to be in the header file?

Answer (score 0):

#### Static method

You need to put the method inside the Student class and mark it static. You need to remember in the future that unfortunately C++ does not allow const static methods at this point of time, however. You will also only be able to manipulate "global", "file-scope static", or "static member data" variables.

That is petty much all about it. You could write this:

```
class MyClass {
   public:
      static int getNumStudents() { return totalStudentsCreated; }
};
```

Then you would call the method this way:

```
int numStudents = MyClass::getNumStudents();
```

or

```
int numStudents = myClass.getNumStudents();
```

Although, this latter may not work with all the compilers out there, so try to stick to the former variant.

#### Static function (without Class)

If you only need a static function without an external class, then you could write the following:

```
static int getNumStudents() { return totalStudentsCreated; }
```

and then use it as follows:

```
int numStudents = getNumStudents();
```